# Shutting down to install update

Tags: macos, software-update

Is shutting down to install updates not a thing anymore? I used to download updates, cancel when it prompted to restart, shut down the machine, and it would start installing the update, and finish the installation the next time I started it. That was a fairly efficient procedure for an office machine. It seems in recent macOS iterations that’s not a thing anymore? Updates are only installed when rebooted explicitly?

Comment: It wasn't ever a thing.

Comment: Yes, certainly in the past, if the OS had downloaded an update, then at Shutdown, you would be asked if you wanted to run the installation now, or at next boot. I don't know whether that's still the case: but it depends on the update being downloaded first.

Comment: @Marc Sure, I’ve only done it for years.

Comment: I wasn't clear.  You see a difference between shutting down the machine, and then powering it back on, vs just restarting it.  I do not.

Comment: @Marc It is convenient when using the machine in the office. I want to work with it all day, letting it restart and install updates for half an hour is something of a disruption during the day. But it's entirely fine to let it shut down and do a bit of installation work, and then let it finish up the next morning when I turn it on again.

Comment: @Marc Yes, I *can* live with having to set aside some time to let it do its updates with a reboot… it just used to be a thing, and I have noticed that it doesn't seem to be anymore. Hence the question.

Comment: Since macOS Catalina, the operating system is stored on a separate read-only system volume (to avoid users modifying the operating system that could corrupt the operating system). So I think some updates (but not all) can be installed in the background whilst you work in the Mac's data volume. From macOS Big Sur onwards, the computer boots off a snapshot of the last installed update of macOS, so that if something does get corrupted during the day, it can rollback to the last installed update of macOS. Search up Signed System Volume for more info about how this works!